# RSA signature verification failing with libtomcrypt

Tags: c, openssl, mbedtls, libtomcrypt

I was using libtomcrypt for a project, in particular hashing and signing with RSA some data. Because of memory requirements I wanted to switch to mbedtls. However I noticed an issue when trying to verify with mbedtls a signature generated by libtomcrypt. There is a padding (PKCS#1 PSS) decoding issue.

Because I didn't know which of these libraries was (maybe) having a bug I used openssl to verify.

I successfully verified a signature generated with mbedtls with openssl and I had a verification failure when verifying one generated form libtomcrypt which makes me think libtomcrypt has a bug.

However because It could be a configuration issue so I created a repo with minimal examples with the hope someone could detect an issue coming from me and not from the library itself.

The test repo is [here](https://github.com/LittleMonsterFr/mbedtls-tomcrypt)

Thanks for any help received !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's one important part missing, you should not be signing the data, but a hash of the data.

Adding this fixes the issue:

```
diff --git a/test-rsa-sign-verify-libtomcrypt-openssl.c b/test-rsa-sign-verify-
libtomcrypt-openssl.c
index 758994a..25e1312 100644
--- a/test-rsa-sign-verify-libtomcrypt-openssl.c
+++ b/test-rsa-sign-verify-libtomcrypt-openssl.c
@@ -9,6 +9,7 @@
 #include "openssl/err.h"
 #include "openssl/rsa.h"

+#define ERRORe(e) printf("%d: \"%s\"\n", __LINE__, error_to_string(e));
 #define ERROR() printf("Error at line : %d\n", __LINE__);

 char *data = "This is the data which will be hashed and then signed by RSA";
@@ -57,10 +58,18 @@ int main(void)
     printf("* Random number generator registered\n");

     size_t data_length = strlen(data);
+
+    uint8_t hash[32];
+    unsigned long hash_length = sizeof(hash);
+    if ((err = hash_memory(hash_idx, data, data_length, hash, &hash_length)) != CRYPT_OK) {
+       ERRORe(err);
+       return -1;
+    }
+
     unsigned long signature_length = 256;
     unsigned char *signature = calloc(signature_length, sizeof(unsigned char));

-    err = rsa_sign_hash((const unsigned char *) data, data_length,
+    err = rsa_sign_hash((const unsigned char *) hash, hash_length,
                         signature, &signature_length,
                         NULL, prng_idx, hash_idx, 12,
                         &private_key);
```